# Can I call a vb.net dll from a c#.net dll?

Tags: .net

Simple yes/no question : Can I call a vb.net function compiled in a vb.net dll from a c# function compiled in its own C# dll? Running in the same application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just to explain it a little: C#, VB.NET and all others are compiled into IL-Code, the syntax is similar to Assembler. So, no matter in what language the Application/Library was written, it will end up as IL-Code.

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can. The other way round isn't necessarily true because you can do things in C# that aren't CLS Compliant, hence the reason you need to mark C# assemblies with

```
[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]
```

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of .NET is interoperability.  Therefore, all .NET language assemblies should be able to call back and forth to other .NET assemblies, with a few very specific caveats, as noted by Pete.

Answer (score 4):

Yes ofcourse. You can access the dll and can create objects of classes in the dll and call methods.

Answer (score 1):

yes, why because .net is language interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the access modifier of the class and its method/function.  Below is a list of access modifiers (C# / VB.Net) and the external availability.

**public / Public** - Yes 
**protected / Protected** - *Must be inherited and the subclass can be used.* 
**internal / Private** - No 
**protected internal / Friend** - No 
**private / Protected Friend** - No