# Late binding calling to a c# DLL from a vb.net DLL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll

I know the question above is possible as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679530/can-i-call-a-vb-net-dll-from-a-c-net-dll), but I am struggling to understand why it is failing in my application.

I have a vb.net dll that is calling a c# dll. This is a third party dll so I have no control over it. I know it is written and compiled to .net 4.5.

If I write a simple .net 4.5 application in vb.net and late call the dll everything is working fine. The instance is created and I can make calls to the methods.

```
        Dim comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyDLL.MyClass", True)
        _comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comType)
```

However if I make the same calls from the vb.net dll it give me the error when I try to create the instance

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
>      at DesktopApi.Native.PInvoke.Init()
>      at DesktopApi.DesktopApi..ctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

Option Strict is off, Option Explicit is On. It is compiling to a target cpu of x86. These options are no different to the simple application I created.

Anyone any ideas? I have searched the net but not finding anything. The infuriating thing is that all this used to work until a update from the supplier. And because it works in the simple application they are not really interested.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I make a simple call of myDl = new MyDll.

Comment: SEHException is always very nasty.  Not specific to C# code, when you see PInvoke.Init() back in the stack trace then you have a pretty good guarantee that it is using unmanaged code.  Which can easily fail in a nasty way.  Digging out its ErrorCode property value is pretty essential to have a guess at the underlying reason, use Try/Catch so you can look at the exception object's InnerException property.  And enable unmanaged debugging so the debugger gets more chatty in the Output window.

Comment: I am struggling to get this to debug. The DLL itself has to run on a server where all the other required dlls are. I have edited the code to add a try catch and list out the inner exceptions but just gives the PInvoke.Init message.

Comment: Not a solution but;
I created a slimed down version of the code and this works OK. Created a smaller application using the DLL and all Ran OK. It looks like a memory issue with either my main application, or the DLL.